# How to create gridview list item like that

Tags: android, gridview, listitem

How i can create this black container with some text like it is on this  picture?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="#aaee00"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Dummy text"
    android:textColor="#eeffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.